# Alternate order by logic in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm looking to allow for a custom ordering logic through mySQL that allows the following data set:

```
+----+-----------------+------------+-------+--+
| ID |      item       | Popularity | Views |  |
+----+-----------------+------------+-------+--+
|  1 | A special place |          3 |    10 |  |
|  2 | Another title   |          5 |    12 |  |
|  3 | Words go here   |          1 |    15 |  |
|  4 | A wonder        |          2 |     8 |  |
+----+-----------------+------------+-------+--+
```

To return an order that alternates, row by row, by popularity and then by views, so the return results look like:

```
+----+-----------------+------------+-------+--+
| ID |      item       | Popularity | Views |  |
+----+-----------------+------------+-------+--+
|  3 | Words go here   |          1 |    15 |  |
|  2 | Another title   |          5 |    12 |  |
|  4 | A wonder        |          2 |     8 |  |
|  1 | A special place |          3 |    10 |  |
+----+-----------------+------------+-------+--+
```

Where you will see the first row returns the 'most popular', the second row returns the most views, the third row returns the second most popular, and the 4th row returns the 2nd most views.

Currently I'm gathering an entire table through mySQL twice, and then merging these results in PHP. This isn't going to cut it when the database is large. Is this possible in mysql at all?

Comment: Why do you want the rows sorted like that?

Comment: Yes, it's possible- although I like your current approach too

Comment: You can do this type of sort in PHP with `usort`, not sure how to do it in MySQL directly though.

Comment: It's for a product search results query I'm working on. It's a neat way to allow products to show up that are most popular, interspersed with new products. The above table is just for illustrative purposes and not representative of actual data.

Comment: @Strawberry how would you approach it in mySQL? Would you consider PHP too heavy on resource? At the moment it's fine with PHP on 200 ish products, but I fear two queries on a large DB and then running a merge on the two will be a bit intense.

Comment: While I don't know how efficient it would be, you could select all the records by popularity descending, with an additional column of "row number" which starts at 1 and increments by 1 each row returned, and grab every *even* row. You could then do the same for `views` descending, grab every *odd* row. Union them. Select from that result set, sort by the new column ascending.

Comment: I suspect this would cause issues with duplicate rows.

Comment: If you grab odds from one and evens from the other with sorting on each, as I've outlined, there should be no duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess something along these lines could work. Consider the following:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,x INT NOT NULL
,y INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1,3,10),
(2,5,12),
(3,1,15),
(4,2, 8)
(5,4, 1);
```

We can rank x and y in turn, and then arrange those ranks in a single list - so will have x1,y1,x2,y2,etc - but all rows will appear twice; once for the x rank and once for the y rank...

```
       SELECT * FROM 
       (
         ( SELECT a.*, COUNT(*) rank FROM my_table a JOIN my_table b ON b.x <= a.x GROUP BY a.id )
          UNION ALL
         ( SELECT a.*, COUNT(*) rank FROM my_table a JOIN my_table b ON b.y <= a.y GROUP BY a.id )
       ) n
       ORDER BY rank

       +----+---+----+------+
       | id | x | y  | rank |
       +----+---+----+------+
       |  5 | 4 |  1 |    1 |
       |  3 | 1 | 15 |    1 |
       |  4 | 2 |  8 |    2 |
       |  4 | 2 |  8 |    2 |
       |  1 | 3 | 10 |    3 |
       |  1 | 3 | 10 |    3 |
       |  5 | 4 |  1 |    4 |
       |  2 | 5 | 12 |    4 |
       |  2 | 5 | 12 |    5 |
       |  3 | 1 | 15 |    5 |
       +----+---+----+------+
```

Now we can just grab the lowest rank for each id...

```
SELECT id
     , x
     , y
  FROM
     (
       ( SELECT a.*, COUNT(*) rank FROM my_table a JOIN my_table b ON b.x <= a.x GROUP BY a.id )
         UNION ALL
       ( SELECT a.*, COUNT(*) rank FROM my_table a JOIN my_table b ON b.y <= a.y GROUP BY a.id )
     ) m
 GROUP
    BY id,x,y
 ORDER
    BY MIN(rank);
+----+---+----+
| id | x | y  |
+----+---+----+
|  3 | 1 | 15 |
|  5 | 4 |  1 |
|  4 | 2 |  8 |
|  1 | 3 | 10 |
|  2 | 5 | 12 |
+----+---+----+
```

Incidentally, this should be faster with variables - but I cannot make that solution work at present - senior moment, perhaps.

Comment: Hell yeah- this looks pretty great. I'll do some tests with this logic and check this as correct if all good. Thanks for your help.